# find the sum of the sequence for n terms, $(1/(1+1^2+1^4)) + (2/(1+2^2+2^4)) + (3/(1+3^2+3^4)) $...

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question is about finding sum of a sequence, 
find the sum of the sequence for n terms,
 $(1/(1+1^2+1^4)) + (2/(1+2^2+2^4)) + (3/(1+3^2+3^4)) $...

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint/Outline:**

You want
$$
S_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4}
$$

Observe that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{k}{1+k^2+k^4} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-k+k^2}-\frac{1}{1+k+k^2}\right)\\
&=
 \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+(k-1)+(k-1)^2}-\frac{1}{1+k+k^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
and try to find the answer by leveraging the fact that it yields a telescopic series.

**Answer** (for verification):

> You should find that $$S_n =\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+n+n^2}\right) =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{1+n+n^2}.$$